# Create model in QGIS where the output overwrites the input

Tags: model, processing, gis, builder, qgis

Hello can somebody help me out. I want to create a simple model in QGIS which you have an input point layer lets called A then inside the model with field calculators it calculates two new columns $x and $y  or any other value, then it saves it back to the input layer A. I need to create a simple model that calculates a column and then it updates or overwritten the original input layer. Is that posible?. I am trying to avoid the temporary output final layer or a new layer. I just want to keep the existing on the layer panel
thank you